# Array displays values in rails console . But return undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass in log

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a helper method which returns array

```
def site
  return Website::SITE.collect!{ |arr| arr if arr[1] != 'site_builder' }
end
```

Website::SITE  return array in console

I call this method in view.

```
- site.each do |menu|
    tr
      td= menu[0]
```

Here it gives ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass):

Comment: Can you please post the output of `Website::SITE` or how you defined the `Website::SITE` variable? I guess it's a 1D array, so when you try to access via `arr[1]`, it gives error.

Comment: [["About ", "about"], ["Calendar", "calendar"], ["Gallery", "gallery"], ["Information", "information"], ["Manage ", "manage"], nil, ["Template", "website"]]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's redefine the function like this:

```rb
def site
   Website::SITE.compact.select{ |arr| arr if arr[1] != 'site_builder' }
end
```

It's because, the array `Website::SITE` contains `nil` value.

`[["About ", "about"], ["Calendar", "calendar"], ["Gallery", "gallery"], ["Information", "information"], ["Manage ", "manage"], nil, ["Template", "website"]]`

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't put the method in the helpers folder but directly to the controller, then you have to add a line of code after your method to make it work.

```
def site
  return Website::SITE.collect!{ |arr| arr if arr[1] != 'site_builder' }
end
helper_method :site
```

This should fix the error

Comment: Helper method is written inside helpers folder.